# It's giving error state.users.find is not a function but I have passed mapStateToProps as argument in the connect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
import React from 'react'
```

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchUser }from "../actions"

class UserHeader extends React.Component {

```
componentDidMount(){

    this.props.fetchUser(this.props.userId);
}
render() {

  const { user } = this.props;
     
    if(!user)
    {
        return <div>Loading..</div>;
    }

    return <div className="header">{user.name}</div>;
}
```

}

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state , ownProps) => {
return {user : state.users.find(user => user.id === ownProps.userId)}
```

}

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ fetchUser })(UserHeader);
```

Comment: Your `state.users `  might not be an array?

Comment: yeah, I get it thanks a lot :)